# Modinizer test if color input type is available

Tags: javascript

In our app we have several html5 color inputs where the user can choose background colors and such. I was just testing in ie and noticed that the color picker doesn't want to work and is not supported.

To fix this I found a shim and was going to plug it into Modinizer. However I can't seem to figure out how to test for it in the load and can't really find any examples.

My code looks like this

```
 {
  test: //window.Color ??,
  nope: ['spectrum.js', 'spectrum.css']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Cihad Turhan told you in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29606926/3702797), mod**er**nizr isn't able to detect this feature.

However, you can test it yourself, by checking the value of such an input.
The default value when supported is "#000000", if it is not supported, the value will be an empty string.

```js
//load event is commented 'cause it won't fire in this empty snippet
//document.addEventListener('load', function(){

  var input = document.createElement('input');
 input.setAttribute('type', "color");

 if (input.value === "") {
  // same as input.value !== "#000000"
    applyYourShimHere();
    }

//  }, false)

function applyYourShimHere() {
  alert("your browser doesn't support color input");
  }
```

Comment: I was trying to use Modinizer to add a fallback when there is no color input for the entire app, not just a few fields. Plus when the color input is not supported it still gives the user a hex value to edit.

Comment: @zazvorniki If it's true for one, it will be for every one… See the edit, actually I missed the fact that IE throws an error when applying "color" for the `type` attribute. So it's ugly but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

On modernizr website it's [clearly stated](http://modernizr.com/docs/#inputtypes) that

> HTML5 introduces thirteen new values for the 's type attribute.
>   They are as follows: search, tel, url, email, datetime, date, month,
>   week, time, datetime-local, number, range, **color**. These types can
>   enable native datepickers, colorpickers, URL validation, and so on. If
>   a browser doesn’t support a given type, it will be rendered as a text
>   field. **Modernizr cannot detect** that date inputs create a datepicker,
>   **the color input create a colorpicker**, and so on—it will detect that
>   the input values are sanitized based on the spec. In the case of
>   WebKit, we have received confirmation that sanitization will not be
>   added without the UI widgets being in place.

So, unfortunately modernizr doesn't give you any clue about html5 inputs.